# How do you parse the logs of multiple servers?

Tags: logs

I usually log in to the server with SSH, and parse the logs(grep/sed/awk/etc...) to trouble shoot an error. I have heard that this to some is the old fashion way of parsing log, but I have yet to find out the new way of doing this?

Is there a newer way of parsing logs?

Comment: https://github.com/kahun/awesome-sysadmin#log-management

Comment: Look into Splunk.

Comment: @DopeGhoti suggests Splunk, which does work nicely. A completely Opensource alternative is Elastic https://www.elastic.co/.